# Why I'm getting this error when trying to get an array's length in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

using npm MongoDB (MongoDB native drive) "mongodb": "^3.1.8",

When I use Robo 3T to get the size of an array, it works fine and I get the length of the array. However, I keep getting the following error in nodejs:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is the error, in length:

```
const getLength = (query) => {
    db = Connection.db.collection('tweets');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let lengthOfData = db.findOne({key: query}).tweets.length
        resolve(lengthOfData);
    });
}
```

This is the figure of the query in Robo 3T:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindOne already returns a promise (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne):

```
const getLength = key => Connection
  .db
  .collection('tweets')
  .findOne({ key })
  .then(item => item.tweets.length);
```